# Каракули вместо кириллицы

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, bottle

При отправке get или post запроса и чтение его с помощью `request.query` и `request.form.get()` вместо русских букв получаю каракули на подобии этих: Ð½Ðµ. Сервер на bottle.

Как получить нормальный текст на русском?

Comment: Думаю явно указать кодировку utf8 в документе.

Comment: Что значит явно указать? Сохранить с кодировкой или написать код типо меты?

Comment: @vyachko для начала сохранять с нужной кодировкой (**utf8**), ну и конечно же явно указать кодировку в самом документе html - **<meta charset="utf-8">**

Comment: @MoloF сохранил и указал в документе, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: @vyachko на сервере необходимо проделать те же операции. Сохранить документ в нужной кодировке и указать при запросе кодировку явно соответственно. вот документация https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html поищите там **CTRL+F** - **charset** . **response.charset = 'utf8'** вот

Comment: @MoloF если использовать ```response.charset = 'utf8'``` выходит ошибка AttributeError: can't set attribute, а если использовать ```response.content_type = 'text/html; charset=utf8'```, то ничего не изменится

Comment: @vyachko тогда прошу предоставить ваш код серверной части. Мои догадки и беглая гуглежка за вас не дала результатов, А телепатические способности закончились.

Comment: @MoloF в том то и дело, что я уже все сам это пытался делать и не получилось, а в коде нет ничего выдающегося - форма отправляющая get и ```request.query['word']```